# postgres_fdw pushing down sum and count, but not min and max

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgres-fdw

As of PostgreSQL 10.x, foreign tables support aggregate pushdown.

I noticed that sum and count operations are being pushed to the remote server but min and max are not pushed the same way.

```
 select min(col) from foreign_table
```

shows a foreign scan with an ORDER BY, followed by a LIMIT applied locally.

In my case, the remote server is actually Redshift rather than another PostgreSQL instance, so this is going to be slower than issuing the `min` right on the query the same way a sum or count would have been, and oddly, if you do a query like

```
 select count(col), min(col) from foreign_table
```

the `min` *will* be pushed on the query.

Why is postgres_fdw treating min/max differently and is there an optimizer setting that will get min/max to be treated same as other aggregate functions?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the best and fastest way to do it. Did you test your assertion that “this is going to be slower than issuing the `min` right on the query”?

PostgreSQL fetches tuples from executor nodes on demand, so what will happen is that *the first row* is fetched from the foreign scan (via the index), then the `LIMIT` will be done and no more rows will be fetched. This is essentially the same thing that would happen if the `min` were executed remotely.

Comment: This is only true if the remote column is indexed.  If you have to do a full scan, sorting is O(N log N) while searching for min is O(N) -- the remote server doesn't know you only care about the first row returned.  In my case the remote server is Redshift, so the characteristics of sort vs. min are also different.

Comment: You show no evidence for the assertion in the last sentence. Are you using remote estimates? If yes, the existence of non-existence of a remote index will influence the plan chosen.